# A tool for completing data on forms

Tags: forms, testing, automation

I work in a low-code system and create web forms. I would like to automate my work so that during the tests I do not have to enter all the data every time. Of course, there are plugins that allow you to complete the content such as first name, last name, etc. But I would also like check checboxes, radio buttons and it's nice if it clicks by itself, confirm, calculate or continue after some time. Is there a tool or another way that will make it possible?

Comment: This question is missing a lot of context and that will make it difficult for someone to provide an answer. For example, you work in a "low-code" system. What system specifically do you use? Does it provide any testing hooks?  How are you testing it? Do you. use a tool or tools, like Selenium? Give more information about your workflow so that we can understand your process.

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.